# Probability of maximum of two uniform random variables

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

The random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent, each with the
uniform distribution on $[−1, 1]$.

Find: $$P[\max (X,Y) >0.5]$$
Apparently there is an easy approach without integration, but I am having trouble visualizing it. Thoughts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Expected value of max(x, y)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/560501/expected-value-of-maxx-y)

Answer (score 2):

Draw the square $[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$.  Shade in the region where $X$ or $Y$ is greater than $0.5$.  Calculate the proportion of the shaded area to the area of the square.

Answer (score 1):

Simply note that
\begin{align*}
P\big(\max (X,Y) >0.5\big) &=1-P\big(\max (X,Y) \le 0.5\big)\\
&=1- P\big((X\le 0.5)\cap (Y\le 0.5)\big)\\
&=1-P\big((X\le 0.5)\big)P\big((Y\le 0.5)\big).
\end{align*}